# Test case to check state update doesn't seem to be giving a correct output

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have a simple function that toggles the state of a component from true to false on a click event.
**Here is the function**

```
public toggleAvailability(dayTime: string): void {
    const isAvailable = this.state[dayTime] === false ? true : false;

    this.setState(
      { [dayTime]: isAvailable }, 
      () => {
      const instructor = {
        userId: this.props.userId,
        availability: this.state.friEarlyAfternoon
      };
      this.props.updateInstructor(instructor);
    });
  }
```

I am using Jest+Enzyme for unit tests and I am trying to test my toggle function as follows:

```
describe('Method toggleAvailability()', () => {
    function test_toggleAvailability(dayTime: string, currentState: boolean, toggledState: boolean): void {
      beforeEach(() => {
        wrapper.setState({
          dayTime: currentState,
        });
        wrapper.instance().toggleAvailability(dayTime);
      });

      it(`Sets the state's ${dayTime} to ${toggledState}`, () => {
        expect(wrapper.state().dayTime).toEqual(toggledState);
      });
    }
    test_toggleAvailability('monEarlyMorning', false, true);
    test_toggleAvailability('monEMorning', true, false);
  });
```

For some reason I cannot get my tests to pass. I am getting this: 
[image]

Anyone got a suggestion here?

Answer (score 0):

Any time you're setting state based on existing state, you **must** use the callback version of `setState` and the state argument it passes you, because [state updates are asynchronous and can get batched together](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous).

So this:

```
const isAvailable = this.state[dayTime] === false ? true : false;
this.setState(
  { [dayTime]: isAvailable }, 
  () => {
  const instructor = {
    userId: this.props.userId,
    availability: this.state.friEarlyAfternoon
  };
  this.props.updateInstructor(instructor);
});
```

should be this, where you're passing in a function for the first argument as well:

```
this.setState(
  prevState => {
    const isAvailable = prevState[dayTime] === false ? true : false;
    return { [dayTime]: isAvailable };
  },
  () => {
    const instructor = {
      userId: this.props.userId,
      availability: this.state.friEarlyAfternoon
    };
    this.props.updateInstructor(instructor);
  }
);
```

---

Side note: Or if you don't actually need strict equality on that `=== false`, you could just use `!`:

```
this.setState(
  prevState => ( { [dayTime]: !prevState[dayTime] } ),
  () => {
    const instructor = {
      userId: this.props.userId,
      availability: this.state.friEarlyAfternoon
    };
    this.props.updateInstructor(instructor);
  }
);
```

Comment: I guess, writing `const isAvailable = this.state[dayTime] === false ? true : false;
this.setState(
  { [dayTime]: isAvailable }, ` or using functional setState is one and the same thing since OP is not actually mutating the state. The problem lies in the test case

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri: How is `[dayTime]: newFlagHereBasedOnState` not mutating state? The test case may *also* be flawed (I don't use the tool in question, can't say; if you say so, I believe you :-) ), but the callback version of `setState` is required here.